Converting Sony x.v.Color / xvYCC video into format supported by Apple devices
My Sony camera is producing video in 8 bits/channel H.264 with a color space that Get Info in macOS Finder doesn't have a textual name for but just lists as (1-11-1). ffprobe says yuv420p(tv, bt709/bt709/iec61966-2-4, progressive), which indicates that transfer function 11 means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XvYCC . Searching apple.com for information about xvYCC, x.v.Color, or IEC 61966-2-4 does not result in indication of support, which one might expect given that Finder doesn't know about the CICP triple.
What software can I use to convert these videos into a wide-gamut format that Apple devices with Apple playback software support without clipping the gamut to sRGB?
